# Пишет ошибку: open java runtime 8+ required with JavaFX на macOS

Tags: java, javafx, runtime

Че делать? Че он хочет?(Пытался запустить Devel Next)[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Решено! Надо было поставить LibericaJRE1.8

Comment: хочет java c библиотекой javafx, P.S. openjdk поставляется без javafx

Comment: А где её взять?

Comment: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-mac

Comment: Ну я установил, пк перезагрузил, но он все равно ошибку выдает.

Comment: в консоли `java -version` что пишет?

Comment: Вот: https://ibb.co/CJVpQyz

Comment: вроде правильно, ну можете попробовать ниже версию поставить 11 или 8

Comment: Ни 11 ни 8 не сработало) одна и та же ошибка

Comment: Попробуйте скачать `Liberica Full JRE 8u312+7 x86 64 bit для macOS`. найдите путь до файла java (скорее всего он внутри bin). и выполните в консоли: "путь_ до_ java -jar путь_до_devel_next_jar". В маке были свои сложности с java, учитывая что она идет в комплекте с осью и обычный дабл клик может игнорировать сторонние установки и обращаться к системной, в которой исключен модуль javafx.